# Как с помощью find() я могy перебирать массив

Tags: javascript

```js
  const a = [{
    name: "john",
    last: [{
      first: "uno",
      second: "due"
    }]
  }];
  const x = a.find(item => item.last.first);
  console.log(x)
```

Как с помощью find() я могy перебирать массив до `first`? Теперь я получил undefined.

Comment: Там нечего перебирать, всего по одному элементу в каждом массиве... `console.log(a[0].last[0].first);`

Comment: Никак. Find не предназначен для перебора массива.

Comment: И что значит «перебрать до first»?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, для примера когда я делаю так: const arr = [1,2,3,4] const x = arr.find(item => item === 2); console.log(x) Я могу получать то значение из arr который соответствует item === 2; A как сделать аналогичные действия с моим примером? то есть что-то в этом роде: const x = a.find(item => item.last[0].first === "uno"); console.log(x). когда я делаю эти действия и не получается ничего

Comment: @Asking, еще раз: в каждом массиве по одному элементу... так _что ты собрался искать, когда возможный путь к конечному свойству всего **один**_? Поиск среди одного значения - лишен смысла.

Comment: Вот опиши простыми словами: как ты представляешь поиск значения `1` в таком массиве: `[1]`? И оправдан ли такой поиск с точки зрения здравого смысла, как ты считаешь... может просто я чего-то не догоняю.

Answer (score 5):

```js
const a = [{
    name: "john",
    last: [{
      first: "uno",
      second: "due"
    }]
  }];
  const x = a.find(item => item.last[0].first === "uno");
  console.log(x)
```

---

> Я хочу с помощью find() найти "uno" из first

`find` этого не делает.

```js
const a = [{
    name: "john",
    last: [{
      first: "uno",
      second: "due"
    }]
  }];
  const x = a.map(item => item.last[0].first);
  console.log(x)
```

Comment: для примера когда я делаю так:
`const arr = [1,2,3,4]
const x = arr.find(item => item === 2);
console.log(x)`
Я могу получать то значение из `arr` который соответствует `item === 2`;
A как сделать аналогичные действия с моим примером?
то есть что-то в этом роде:
`const x = a.find(item => item.last[0].first === "uno");
console.log(x)`. 
когда я делаю эти действия и не получается ничего

Comment: @Asking Что значит "ничего"? Что выводится в консоль?

Comment: выводится : `{ name: 'john', last: [ { first: 'uno', second: 'due' } ] }`

Comment: @Asking Теперь самое время сказать, какой результат Вы ожидали.

Comment: Я хочу с помощью find() найти  "uno"  из `first`.